# JqueryUI, Datepicker and Codeigniter: How to change format on load?

Tags: php, jquery-ui, codeigniter, datepicker

Short version:

In a input field I have a date displayed in 'yy-mm-dd' format. I want to take it via jqueryUI and format that date to 'dd. MM yy' and put it back in the input field.

The problem I am having is that when I get the value from that input field it doesn't know which format it is.

Long version:

In my database i save the date in a typical format "yy-mm-dd". However, for display purposes when using a date picker I use "dd. MM yy", while on the hidden field i save the "yy-mm-dd".

When I load the entry to edit its date in the field that is being displayed is "yy-mm-dd" and I want it too be "dd. MM yy".

```
$(function() {
    // in my rjquery.ui.datepicker-.... is the "dd. MM yy" set as dateFormat
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['....']); 

    $( "#datepicker_date" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        altField: "#alt_date_field",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd" 
    });





});
```

What I am unable to do is to when the page loads, I guess `$(document).ready(function() {});`, is to take the date that is in the #datepicker_date, convert it to 'dd. MM yy' format and then put it back in #datepicker_date field.

For the added bonus I would like first to see what format it is and if it is 'yy-mm-dd' then to convert it (because due to validation in codeigniter the field will be repopulated with the correct format since they will take the correct format).

So kinda:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if(  the_format_of_the_date_in_#datepicker_date == 'yy-mm-dd')
        //convert it to 'dd. MM yy' and set it to #datepicker_date


});
```

I hope that I wasn't too confusing. I know this is simple but I am just unable to make it work, I appreciate any help.

EDIT:

I load the data via the php and codeigniter form_helper and validator set_value() method.

```
echo form_label('Date:');
$data = array(
     'name'        => 'date',
     'id'       => 'datepicker_date',
     'readonly' => 'readonly'


 );
echo form_input($data, set_value('date', $date_loaded_via_controller));
```

Comment: How do you load the date, using `php` ?

Comment: Do you load the date from the hidden field ?

Comment: @SheikhHeera I edited the question. I load using php from the controller, I populate both the hidden field and the display field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (from my working project's CI helper function)

```
$date_loaded_via_controller="2012-12-15"; // suppose you have this date
$date_loaded_via_controller=date_to_dmy($date_loaded_via_controller);
function date_to_dmy($dt)
{
    $date=explode(' ', $dt);
    $deli=strpos($dt, '/') ? '/':'-';
    $date=explode($deli, $date[0]);
    $newdt= $date[2].".".$date[1]." ".$date[0]; // for 15.12 2012
    return $newdt;
}
echo form_input($data, set_value('date', $date_loaded_via_controller));
```

You can keep this function in the helper file and load it before you use.

Comment: Thank you for your input. But the problem here isn't just changing the orders in the d m y. The format dd. MM yy will display something like '03. December 2012'. And since in the regionals are the translation of the months it is important that I acutally use the jQuery UI functions.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY found the answer.

As you know I use two fields one hidden and one for presentation, that way in the database the common one is saved (the 'yy-mm-dd' one). What I have been trying to do is to convert from one format to another when loading the date from the database for editing.

So, instead of me trying to convert it, the solution is to simply use the datepickers 'setDate' function and let it take care of it.

I do this by adding the datepicker on the #alt_date_field and there set the altfield and altformat to the one for displaying.

```
$("#alt_date_field").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        altField: "#datepicker_date",
        altFormat: "dd. MM yy" 
    });
```

And then when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ult_date_field').datepicker('setDate',$('#alt_date_field').val());
});
```

What I did here is take the value of the hidden input field and use the setDate method so that it will populate the #datepicker_date in the correct format.